Whether the missing value depends on other feature/variable or not
I am solving a data science problem. In which I have 20 features thos are

dateCrawled: Date the car was crawled. (Date)
name: Name of the car. (String)
seller: Type of seller (private or dealer). (String)
offerType: Type of offer (e.g. sale, repair, etc.). (String)
price: Price of the car. (Integer)
abtest: Test type (A or B). (String)
vehicleType: Type of vehicle (e.g. SUV, sedan, etc.). (String)
yearOfRegistration: Year the car was registered. (Integer)
gearbox: Type of gearbox (manual or automatic). (String)
powerPS: Power of the car in PS. (Integer)
model: Model of the car. (String)
kilometer: Kilometers the car has been driven. (Integer)
monthOfRegistration: Month the car was registered. (Integer)
fuelType: Type of fuel (e.g. diesel, petrol, etc.). (String)
brand: Brand of the car. (String)
notRepairedDamage: Whether or not the car has any damage that has not been repaired. (String)
dateCreated: Date the car was created. (Date)
nrOfPictures: Number of pictures of the car. (Integer)
postalCode: Postal code of the car. (Integer)
lastSeen: Date the car was last seen. (Date)

from the above features VehicleType, gearbox, model, notRepairedDamage and fuelType having missing.
I want to know whether the missing value of vehicleType depends on any other missing value feature or not, if depends than what to do next. Also, I want to find the relationship between the features for example => model depends on brand or not, vehicleType depends on model or not.
I have performed groupby operation on vehicleType & model, brand & model, fuelType & brand, fuelType & vehicle, etc.
getting the result shown in the image.
In the image i have performed groupby operation on the fuelType & vehicle and fuelType & model.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots (how to format code in posts). Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors? http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode
